# subequation in tabular

Tags: tables

I am trying to number two equations at the same line as subequation.

My problem seems to be due to `case` environment, since if i comment the `case` environment, the problem disappears.

Here is a short example of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{subequations}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{m{0.4\linewidth}}@{}}
   \begin{align}
      \Theta[n] = \begin{cases}
                0, & n < 0, \\
                1, & n \ge 0, 
              \end{cases}
   \end{align} &
   \begin{align}
     m_{ij}^{det} = \left|\Delta_{ij}\right|
   \end{align}
  \end{tabular}
 \end{subequations}                           
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `align` and not `equation`?

Comment: Your example works if you make the change suggested by @egreg. (And add the `array` package, which is missing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{m{0.5\linewidth}@{}}}
\begin{equation}
  \Theta[n] = \begin{cases}
                0, & n < 0, \\
                1, & n \ge 0,
              \end{cases}
\end{equation} &
\begin{equation}
  m_{ij}^{\det} = \left|\Delta_{ij}\right|
\end{equation}
\end{tabular}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Notice the slight changes: I gave half of the linewidth to both equations, removing all intercolumn spaces (and said `\noindent`).

The `det` at the exponent should be in roman type, as it's not the product of three variables, but an abbreviation. The `\det` operator is handy, in other cases it should be `\textup{...}`.

It would have worked also with `align`, provided you put the `cases` environment in a pair of braces (the `&` confuses LaTeX), but `align` is *wrong* when no alignment is done.