# Equation numbers under equations

Tags: tables, numbering, amsmath, subequations

I have three similar equations which I want on a same line. I put them in `tabular` environment nested within `subequations` following this: [subequation in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36662/subequation-in-tabular). Now I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{amstext}
\begin{document}
Here is what I get:\\

\begin{subequations}
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}*{3}{m{0.38\linewidth}@{}}}{}
    \begin{equation}
    (A+B)C=D(E-F)-G  \label{eq:eq1}
    \end{equation} &
    \begin{equation}
    (A+B)C=D(E-F)-H  \label{eq:eq2}
    \end{equation} &
    \begin{equation}
    (A+B)C=D(E-F)-I  \label{eq:eq3}
    \end{equation}
    \end{tabular}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Since my eq's are little bit longer than in the above thread I want numbering under the eq's. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent Equations:

\begin{subequations}
\label{eq:main}
 \begin{align}
  \label{eq:eq1}
  (A+B)C &= D(E-F)-G\\
  \label{eq:eq2}
  (A+B)C &= D(E-F)-H\\
  \label{eq:eq3}
  (A+B)C &= D(E-F)-I
 \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\noindent References: \eqref{eq:main} and \eqref{eq:eq1}--\eqref{eq:eq3}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The `\noindent` is just to avoid indentation of the text.

Comment: That was my first decision, but I want them on a single line and if possible with numbers below and centered.

Comment: @alchemist_ bg I don't know an elegant way of doing this; sorry. (Just out of curiosity: Why do that? It looks very weird to me.)

Comment: I don't know. I just thought that it will look a little better.

Comment: How do you "align" to the '=' instead of the right part of the equations?

Comment: @MarioS.E. With the ampersands.